# django set ModelChoiceField's "to_field_name" to multiple columns

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to provide multiple field names in  Django's modelChoiceField's `to_field_name`

something like

```
field1  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=myModel.objects.all(), required=False,
                   empty_label="--------",
                   
                  to_field_name=["col1, col2"],
                 
                  widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        )
```

I have a model like

```
class Codes(models.Model):
     item_code    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     item_name    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_code + self.item_name
```

Now I can set `queryset` as

```
field1  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Codes.objects.all(), required=False,
                   empty_label="--------",
                                    
                  widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        )
```

And I will get the combination of two fields in my `select` tag options

everything works but when I open the edit page, the select box doesn't show the default selected value

Also, I want a combination of fields because when `item_code` repeats in the database, `to_field_name` gives an error.

Comment: What is your expected result? Probably you may misunderstand the usage of `to_field_name` parameter

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are interpreting `to_field_name` wrong:

According to the Django website (Django [to_field_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name) explained):

> This optional argument is used to specify the field to use as the value of the choices in the field’s widget. Be sure it’s a unique field for the model, otherwise the selected value could match more than one object. By default it is set to None, in which case the primary key of each object will be used...

Which means you can use the `to_field_name` to address the form object in HTML.
But it does not say anything about multiple `to_field_name` values.
Normally the primary key is used to address the object. If you set the `to_field_name` then that field will be used.

To actually add data into the `modelChoiceField` object, you would need to do something like this.

```
class CustomForm(ModelForm):
    muscles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                        queryset=None,
                        to_field_name='name',
                        required=False,)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].queryset = Users.objects.all()
```

Comment: yeah, I understand `to_field_name` requires a unique field for the model, but in my case, a combination of two fields is always unique, but not one field. That's why I was wondering if this is even possible to provide multiple fields in `to_field_name`